# Different constants of integration on different intervals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

I tried to prove that on the interval $(-1,\infty)$ that: $$\arctan\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)=\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{4}$$
So I defined: $$f(x)=\arctan\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)-\arctan(x)$$
Then apparently: $$f'(x)=0$$
Therefore $f(x)$ is constant thus:
$$f(x)=\arctan\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)-\arctan(x)=C$$
$$\arctan\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)=\arctan(x)+C$$
Taking $x=0$ gives $C=-\frac{\pi}{4}$
Thus is proven: $$\arctan\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)=\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

QUESTION: Why does $C$ have a different value for $x<-1$? Why does the above reasoning only apply to the interval $(-1,\infty)$ How to find $C$ for $x<-1$?

Comment: $f$ is not defined when $x=-1$.

Comment: @choco_addicted Yes, I understand. Then why is C different for x<-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

$$\arctan\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)$$ and its derivative are not defined at $x=-1$.

For this reason, you are not allowed to say that $f'(-1)=0.$ (You were right to say "apparently" $f(x)=0$.)

Actually, the function has a jump of $-\pi$ at that point, which explains why there is no derivative and why the constants differ. (You can integrate on both sides of $-1$, but not across it.)

Comment: But the question is: why is there a jump? I can see f(x) is not defined at x=-1. But why would the value be different for x<-1?

Comment: @ImreVégh: plot that function.

Comment: I can see there is a jump in the plot. But why are the values different?

Comment: @ImreVégh: what value do you expect at $-1$ ?

Comment: At -1 not defined. But I just don't get why the function I defined as f(x) has a different constant below -1 and above -1.

Comment: @ImreVégh: you don't answer. What value do you expect at $-0.999999$ ?

Comment: In other words, why can I only apply the above reasoning to a certain interval?

Comment: @ImreVégh: what value do you expect at $-0.999999$ ?

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Taking the limit to -1+ and -1- gives different results

Comment: @ImreVégh: yep, by the definition of the arctangent, an odd function. So cannot take a single value for argument $\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

From the Article $240,$ Ex$-5$ of [Plane Trigonometry(by Loney)](http://archive.org/details/planetrigonomet00lonegoog),

$$\arctan x+\arctan y=\begin{cases} \arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy} &\mbox{if } xy<1\\ \pi+\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy} & \mbox{if } xy>1 \\ \text{sgn}(x)\dfrac\pi2 & \mbox{if } xy=1 \end{cases} $$

As $\arctan(-u)=-\arctan u,$

Setting $y=-1,$

$$\arctan x-\dfrac\pi4=\begin{cases} \arctan\frac{x-1}{1+x} &\mbox{if } -x<1\iff x>-1\\ \pi+\arctan\frac{x-1}{1+x} & \mbox{if } -x>1\iff x<-1 \\ -\dfrac\pi2 & \mbox{if } -x=1\iff x=-1 \end{cases} $$

Do you notice tthe different constants?

Comment: Shouldn't $\arctan(-u)=-\arctan u$ since $\arctan$ is an odd function?

Comment: @cr3, definitely